# TWIG, select all columns from database using twig template

Tags: sql, templates, twig

I'm sorry for this silly question but i need your help guys
i want to retrieve all columns from database in TWIG templates

Comment: That's not what twig is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twig doesn't allow to do that to prevent users from adding "business logic" to their templates. If you use Twig inside Symfony framework, you can use the `render()` function to call a PHP method from the template and retrieve those columns.